# Display nav layer on cms page issue

Tags: category, layered-navigation, xml

This is the content of layer/cms.xml file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <cms_page translate="label">
        <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
                <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="menubuilder/menu" name="cms_menu" before="-">
                <action method="setMenuCode">
                    <menu_code>cms_menu</menu_code>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>

    <cms_index_index translate="label">
        <label>CMS Home Page</label>
    </cms_index_index>

    <cms_index_defaultindex>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_defaultindex>

    <cms_index_noroute translate="label">
        <label>CMS No-Route Page</label>
    </cms_index_noroute>

    <cms_index_defaultnoroute>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="default_no_route" template="cms/default/no-route.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_defaultnoroute>

</layout>
```

This is the content of my **cms page design**:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
   <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
</block>
 </reference>
```

I am trying to display the navigation layer using the category id, **3**, but nothing happens. Can someone give me some idea what should I try ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change reference name `content` to `left`

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
   <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
</block>
 </reference>
```

i test it with default theme with cms it working

```
<reference name="content">
          <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
          <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>4</category_id></action>
              <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                   <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                            </block>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>5</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>4</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>3</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>3</count></action>
                            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>2</count></action>
                            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                        </block>
</reference>
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
</block>
 </reference>
```

Comment: I tried content, left, right and I got the same result: no nav layer :( . Any other ideas? thx :)

Comment: did you set the template 2column left ?

Comment: Yes, it it set to 2column with left bar

Comment: check the category in anchor?

Comment: Yes, it is set to in anchor. BTW, thx for trying to help me :)

Comment: i just add follow code in design tab and it start working kindly check there is no extension involved

Comment: It displayes all of products, I have the pagination, but in the col-left sidebar, I only have the mini-menubuilder, without nav layer.  If you check my xml you can see smth about the mini-menubuilder. I have absolutly no idea what is that ? But my quess is somehow there are in conflict

Comment: your question is about display layer nav.  now you want to show mini-menubuilder too?

Comment: no no , you misunderstand me . I said that maybe because of the mini-menubuilder it is not displayed